# How do I install Google voice search on a rooted gb custom rom?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-apps

I recently moved to X-gamer, a gb based stock rom. I flashed gapps for gb thinking I would get back voice search and talk. However it seems only talk got installed. Voice search link on Google play shows 'item not found'. How do I install Google voice search?

Answer (score 0):

> In Android 4.1+ (Jelly Bean), it was merged with Google Now.

But *Google Now* isn't available for 2.3 (Gingerbread).

You have to search & download the last apk-File of voicesearch.

P.S.: If you have "*Connections Errors / Server-Problems*": Try reset the cache of the app.